# How do I add critical chance and damage to Damage Per Ssecond calculations? Or how do I calculate the expected DPS with crit?

Tags: equation

Here is my code, simplified
Damage is calculated like:

```
(DamageMin + DamageMax) / 2) * AttacksPerSecond
```

My attempt at calculating critical chance into DPS: (Crit chance is the percentage integer, 1.5 is the crit multiplier)

```
    (((1 - (CritChance / 100)) * ((DamageMin + DamageMax) / 2)) + (WCrit / 100) * 1.5f)) * AttacksPerSecond
```

This gives me 
nothing close to what the dps should be. What am I doing wrong? How do i calculate the expected damage having, say, 6% crit chance would add to a weapon that does 6 damage and attacks once per second?

Comment: I feel like this depends pretty heavily on what game you’re referring to. Are there no published formulae for your game?

Comment: Why should it depend on the game? The damage, being 6 for example, calculated per second once per second should be 6 dps. Pretty simple. But how do I factor in a 6% critical strike chance?

Comment: @user3569813 Among other things, you seem to assume that damage is uniformly distributed and does not depend on any other variables. I doubt this is true of every game. In addition, this is hardly a programming/software question, and may be more appropriate for Math.SE.